anchor-bankrun test failing, not able to find initialized address [votingDapp program from the solana bootcamp]
This code is the voting_dapp.spec.ts from the solana bootcamp voting program.
crunchyAddress seems to be initialized but it is throwing error while creating crunchyCandidate(error log in attached image).
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor'
import {Program} from '@coral-xyz/anchor'
import {Keypair, PublicKey} from '@solana/web3.js'
import {VotingDapp} from '../target/types/voting_dapp'
import { startAnchor } from 'solana-bankrun';
import { BankrunProvider } from 'anchor-bankrun';
import { Provider } from 'jotai';
import { ok } from 'assert';

const IDL = require('../target/idl/voting_dapp.json');

const votingDappAddress = new PublicKey("94Cw6i5ELpru4PzGVZRZPoo4w7Szzjz48mbFArdgHTT6");

let context;
let provider;
let votingDappProgram: anchor.Program<VotingDapp>;

beforeAll(async () => {
  context = await startAnchor("", [{name: "voting_dapp", programId: votingDappAddress}], []);
  provider = new BankrunProvider(context);
  votingDappProgram = new Program<VotingDapp>(
    IDL,
    provider,
  );
})

describe('voting_dapp', () => {
  it('Initialize Poll', async() => {
    await votingDappProgram.methods.initializePoll(
      new anchor.BN(1),                   // Poll Id 1
      "Which peanut butter do you like more?", // Poll desciption
      new anchor.BN(0),                   // Start time = 0
      new anchor.BN(1829092922),          // End time
    ).rpc();

    const [pollAddress] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8)],
      votingDappAddress,
    )

    console.log(pollAddress);

    const poll = await votingDappProgram.account.poll.fetch(pollAddress);

    console.log(poll);

    expect(poll.pollId.toNumber()).toEqual(1);
    expect(poll.description).toEqual("Which peanut butter do you like more?");
    expect(poll.startTime.toNumber()).toBeLessThan(poll.endTime.toNumber());
    expect(poll.endTime.toNumber()).toEqual(1829092922);
  });

  it('Initialize Candidate', async() => {
    await votingDappProgram.methods.initializeCandidate(
      "Crunchy",
      new anchor.BN(1),
    ).rpc();
    const [crunchyAddress] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8), Buffer.from("Crunchy")],
      votingDappAddress,
    );
    console.log(crunchyAddress);
    const crunchyCandidate = await votingDappProgram.account.candidate.fetch(crunchyAddress);
    // console.log(crunchyCandidate);

    // await votingDappProgram.methods.initializeCandidate(
    //   "Smooth",
    //   new anchor.BN(1),
    // ).rpc();
    // const [smoothAddress] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    //   [new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8), Buffer.from("Smooth")],
    //   votingDappAddress,
    // );
    // const smoothCandidate = await votingDappProgram.account.candidate.fetch(smoothAddress);
    // console.log(smoothCandidate);
  });

  it('Vote', async() => {

  });
});


I have made sure that the program_id is correct and the order of arguments in the #[instruction()] matches throughout the program and the test. Everything seems to be consistent with the way pollAddress was used to create poll account. What could go wrong with the crunchyCandidate?


Solved, if anyone runs into a similar problem in future:
turns out that I had given the seeds in the incorrect order in crunchyAddress. The correct way is
[new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8), Buffer.from("Crunchy")] - based on how I passed the arguments in my #[instruction()] for the InitializeCandidate() account validator in the anchor program in lib.rs
The order of arguments seems to be really important. I think the reason behind this is the serialization/deserialization process, which anchor abstracts away for us.
